# How to create NSPredicate to query specific object from one to many relationship?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities with the following properties:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var identifier: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var latestBoughtDate: Date
    @NSManaged var cars: Set<Car>
}

class Car: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var identifier: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var boughtAt: Date
    @NSManaged var person: Person
}
```

Now I need to create `NSPredicate` to find by search query all persons which name contains given phrase OR its the latest bought car which name contains given phrase:

```
let phrase = "abc" //value from search field
let format = "name CONTAINS [cd] %@ || ANY cars.name CONTAINS [cd] %@"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, phrase, phrase) //searching persons
```

but above example is looking for cards where ANY of its cars' name contains phrase, not the latest bought one. How can I do it? I could use `latestBoughtDate` somehow but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Something like `…|| (cars.name CONTAINS [cd] %@ && cars.date = latestBoughtDate)` maybe could work